# Adding a MySQL StoredProcedure causes not responding state

Tags: mysql, xampp, stored-procedures

I'm on Windows 7 ultimate 32bit + xampp 1.7.2 [MySQL v5.1.37]

This is my stored procedure :

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE updatePoints(IN parentid INT(5),IN userid INT(5))
DECLARE chpoints INT(5);
BEGIN
 SELECT points INTO chpoints FROM quiz_challenges WHERE id = parentid;
 UPDATE quiz_users SET points = points + chpoints WHERE forumid=userid;
END;
//                                   
delimiter ;
```

At first it was showing error 1064 while creating stored procedure.
I added delimiters part and when I tried running the query from phpmyadmin, Firefox went into not responding state.
After that I started Internet Explorer and tried opening my pages which use the same database, it worked fine. However, I tried opening phpmyadmin and IE went into not responding state as well.
I restarted both servers. Later restarted PC. Tried again but its same behavior.

So whats wrong with this tiny little code ? Am I missing something which might be causing infinite loop ?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an issue with phpmyadmin, not the script. (serverfault?)

Comment: Also, one thing I notice is that your DECLARE must appear inside the `BEGIN ... END;` See :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html

Comment: I moved DECLARE inside BEGIN block and it has surely made some difference. Now firefox doesnt go into not responding state, I can use it but it says waiting for localhost and my processor hits 80c mark. Nothing happens after that.
Screenshot after ~1.30 mins of waiting. 
http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/6642/77392131.png
After that I stopped everything to save my processor.

Comment: I'm gonna say definitely phpMyAdmin after looking at the screen shot... try running the query in something like SqlYog or a similar program. mySql isn't freezing, Apache is.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience phpmyadmin does not like the use of `delimiter //` inside the SQL query window. Instead, there is a "delimiter" text box in the phpmyadmin SQL query window, the contents of which are set to ";" by default. Enter "//" in this text box instead of ";", and try your query with the `delimiter //` and `delimiter ;` lines omitted.

Answer (score 0):

## OBSERVATION #1

The order is incorrect. The `DECLARE chpoint INT(5)` should be after `BEGIN`, not before

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE updatePoints(IN parentid INT(5),IN userid INT(5))
BEGIN
 DECLARE chpoints INT(5);
 SELECT points INTO chpoints FROM quiz_challenges WHERE id = parentid;
 UPDATE quiz_users SET points = points + chpoints WHERE forumid=userid;
END;
//                                   
delimiter ;
```

## OBSERVATION #2

You should make sure of the following for `quiz_users`

- `forum_id` is indexed
- `points` **is not indexed** (That's right, I said not indexed because the value would be incremented and cause the BTREE for that column's index to shuffle that key's place in the index).

## OBSERVATION #3

If the PHP script is iterating `parentid` and `userid` values, BIG OUCH !!!

This would indicate that a browser session is doing round trips to feed each call to ther stored procedure. You should think about passing all the `parentid` and `userid` combinations in a table and letting the stored procedure handle it on the server side with doing round trips from the browser session.